# Executing the Button's Command on ListBoxItem Selection

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have this (simplified for SO) listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="CurriculumList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCurriculums}"
            SelectedIndex="0"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="TheButton" 
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    Content="{Binding DisplayMember}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                    Command="{Binding OpenCurriculumEditViewCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I can navigate up and down the listBoxItems with the keyboard to change selection, but it doesn't change the detail view - the `Button` in the `DataTemplate` doesn't actually get clicked, so the `OpenCurriculumEditViewCommand`never gets executed.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to execute `OpenCurriculumEditViewCommand` when the `ListBox` selection changes, you could do the following:

First:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And then..

```
<ListBox x:Name="CurriculumList"
        ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCurriculums}"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" Command="{Binding OpenCurriculumEditViewCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This `ListBox`'s `DataContext` is bound to the `FilteredCurriculums` property, which is a filtered `ICollectionView` of an `ObservableCollection<NavigationItemViewModel>`.  How is the `EventTrigger` going to know which `NavigationItemViewModel` it's binding to for the `Id` and `OpenCurriculumEditViewCommand`?

Comment: I've editted the answer. To bind to the `Id` of the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` you can use it as `RelativeSource` to the `Binding` of your `CommandParameter`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a `Button` at all if you want it to trigger on selection.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, but an alternative approach would be appreciated.  "Don't do it that way", while technically correct, doesn't really _help_.

Comment: Just bind the `SelectedItem` and execute your command's logic in the setter of the bound property. There are several alternatives to this as well, it's not really complicated.